# Property 'getContractFactory' does not exist on type?

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Trying to run `npx hardhat run --network ropsten scripts/deploy.ts`

`deploy.ts` throws a type error

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
// const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  // await hre.run('compile');

  const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter")
  const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, Hardhat!")

  await greeter.deployed()

  console.log("Greeter deployed to:", greeter.address)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  });
```

*Property 'getContractFactory' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/ubuntu/demos/react-dapp/node_modules/ethers/lib/ethers")'.*

Throws an error when `hre` gets removed from `const Greeter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter")` to `await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter")`

source code: https://github.com/GoGetterMeme/react_dapp.git

Answer (score 4):

ethers.getContractFactory is a one of the helpers that Hardhat added to the ethers object so you need to call hre first.

https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers.html#helpers

Notice getContractFactory doesn't exist in the Ethers.js docs:

https://docs.ethers.io/v4/search.html?q=getContractFactory&check_keywords=yes&area=default#

Answer (score 2):

Hardhat exposes a [Hardhat Runtime Environment (HRE)](https://hardhat.org/advanced/hardhat-runtime-environment.html) when running a task, test or script. You can access this via a global object called `hre`.

For example:

```
const Greeter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('Greeter');
```

Answer (score 2):

First, uncomment your `hre` import at the top of your `deploy.ts` script.

```
import hre from 'hardhat'
```

and then call `hre.ethers.getContractFactory`. hardhat extends the `ethers` object with `getContractFactory`, so you need to call it's `hre.ethers` not `ethers`.

Second, make sure you add

```
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers"
```

to the top of your `hardhat.config.ts` file.